# How can I enable cross-OS cut-and-paste in Windows 11 with VMWare Fusion 13 on M1?

Tags: windows, apple-silicon, vmware

I just set up a new MBP with M1 Pro.

- macOS: Ventura 13.0.1
- VMWare Fusion: 13.0 (Pro license)

I installed Windows 11 into a VM based [on this guide](https://cellular.fm/2022/08/03/install-windows-11-arm-vmware-fusion-apple-silicon-m1-m2-mac-macbook-air-pro-imac-macstudio-video/).  I installed VMWare Tools and they appear to be working because I now have network access inside the VM and I can adjust the resolution.

However, there is no option for cross-OS cut-and-paste-- not in the **Edit** menu of VMWare Fusion, and not from any keyboard shortcuts I can find.  How do I enable this feature (or, if it is not available, where are the docs that say it is unsupported)?

Comment: I remember a time when Windows could not support copy/paste between its own programs so expecting across systems…

Comment: @SolarMike VMWare Fusion has supported copy-paste between Windows and macOS since version 1 on Intel.  Apologies if you were trying to be funny/hate on Windows in a Mac forum.

Comment: @PatrickKenny There's nothing to enable.  Copy something to the clipboard on the Mac with CMD-C, paste it in Windows with CTRL-V.

Comment: @MarcWilson That's what I thought, but the keyboard shortcuts aren't working for me.  I can use CTRL+C and CTRL+V to copy and paste within Windows, and CMD+C and CMD+V to do the same within macOS.  But when I CMD+C macOS CTRL+V  Windows, I get nothing (if Windows clipboard is empty) or whatever was in the Windows clipboard.

Comment: @PatrickKenny I know you said the VMWare Tools are installed, but it sounds like they are not.

Comment: @MarcWilson Definitely installed. It turns out VMWare Tools for Arm don't support copy and paste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new VMware Fusion 2023 tech preview has proper VMware Tools.  You don't have to run the tech preview to use the VMware Tools (which are also technically in "preview" form).  You can download the tech preview, mount the DMG, "show package contents" on the app, and find the VMware Tools ISO under Contents/Library/isoimages/arm64.  Mount that ISO in your VM and run the setup file.

[VMware Fusion Public Tech Preview 2023](https://customerconnect.vmware.com/downloads/get-download?downloadGroup=FUS-TP2023)

Presumably, there will be a full release by the end of the year that will make this unnecessary.  (Not sure if it will be VMware Fusion 14, which you would have to pay for, or something like 13.1.)

Update: As of October 20, 2023, VMware Fusion 13.5 is out.  Just use 13.5 (or later) and the VMware Tools bundle built-in should behave just like it does for VMware Fusion on Intel Macs, or VMware Workstation on Windows/Linux.

Comment: The ARM64 tools are still the barebones (SVGA/vmxnet) version in the tech preview as of today, so this solution doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I installed the tech preview and then installed VMware Tools the traditional way. That got me the full version, so I assume the tools were installed from the x86 ISO located at `Contents/Library/isoimages/x86_x64/windows.iso`. The setup.exe binary is x86, but the VMware Tools service it installs is native ARM64.

Comment: I just downloaded it again to double-check... the arm64/windows.iso file definitely has a setup.exe file in it for me.  I just ran the setup and it installed the ARM version of VMware Tools.  (I have not actually installed the VMware Tech preview.  I'm using VMware Fusion 13.0.2, with VMware Tools from the tech preview DMG, and copy/paste works fine.)

Comment: Copying the arm64 image out of the tech preview and mounting it allowed me to install it in my VM on a Macbook Pro M2 Max. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 8):

Based on [a question in the VMWare Forums](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/Mac-Windows-cut-and-paste-support-on-M1/m-p/2943610#M180867), according to the [Unofficial Fusion 13 for Apple Silicon Companion](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Documents/The-Unofficial-Fusion-13-for-Apple-Silicon-Companion/ta-p/2939907?emcs_t=S2h8ZW1haWx8dG9waWNfc3Vic2NyaXB0aW9ufExCTTZMN0czSUJIN005fDI5NDM2MTB8U1VCU0NSSVBUSU9OU3xoSw) (version 4, Dec. 11, 2022):

> Copy/paste and drag/drop does not currently work between the Mac host
> and a Windows 11ARM virtual machine. This is due to Fusion 13’s
> current lack of a full VMware Tools implementation for Windows 11 ARM.
>
> A workaround discovered by the Fusion community is to connect to the
> virtual machine using a RDP client such as Microsoft Remote Desktop for
> the Mac (which does run on Apple Silicon Macs). This will allow
> copy/paste between the Mac and the Windows virtual machine. Note
> that this will only work on Windows 11 Pro and Enterprise editions. It
> will not work on Windows 11Home editions because Microsoft does not
> support enabling remote desktop access on the Home edition.